# TortoiseSVN "Can't Set position pointer in file \SVN\db\revs\0\4 An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file"

Tags: windows, svn, visual-studio-2015, tortoisesvn

I am working on an SVN C++ project that was working without issues with a remote SVN repository, but it started giving me the following errors errors

"Can't Set position pointer in file \SVN\db\revs\0\4 An attempt was made to move the file pointer before the beginning of the file"

And this happened when I try to commit or update or check out the code

I tried the followign steps, and neither one worked

1. Clean-up
2. Delete trunk + make a new trunk from local code
3. Delete entire SVN repository and create a new one from local code

None of this worked, and the same error still comes up.

Everything I looked up said it was a server-side SVN error, but I tried making a repository on the same computer and it still gave me these problems.

Other projects check in and check out fine.

The other issue I have is that it doesn't report which file is the problematic file, is there a way to view the logs and determine if its a file that is causing this problem?

Thanks,
-D

Answer (score 1):

I tried re-creating another repository on the same network drive and it gave me the same error. When I re-created that repository locally, there was no error. 
This leads me to believe it's a networking or firewall issue

Answer (score -1):

You may have .svn files in your local code that might be giving you some trouble. You should try looking for these hidden files and getting rid of them.